# Use model instance to access model's manager 'objects'

Tags: web-development, django, query

In the Django documentation it's mentioned that Django managers are accessible only via model classes rather than model instances to enforce table and record level operations. What are table and record level operations and does they get affected if we use a model instance?I have gone through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187032/what-is-the-difference-between-table-level-operation-and-record-level-operation?rq=1, but was unable to understand much. I am not much acquainted with database. It would be helpful if i can get an example 
to understand the scenario.